# beginner java syntax in calling method

Tags: java, class

I am new to Java, coming from PHP.  Here is a snippet of code:

```
public List<WSOrderInfo> getOrderInfoList() {

    List<WSOrderInfo> detailList = new ArrayList<WSOrderInfo>();
```

I am wondering the following:
What is the term in the angle brackets? (<WSOrderInfo>)
Is this defined as part of some scope of the class?
Does it reference an external variable?

Thanks!

Comment: that's generics https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: Correct, it is generics. It is specifying the `type` that the List will contain. For example, it could be `string`, `MyCoolType`, etc.

Comment: I understand no one knows everything but what happened with searching for an answer before shooting the question. Not necessarily related to this post, but I see so many questions on stackoverflow that it makes me think 'did you try to at least google this' if not go to Java Tutorial :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments these terms are specifying the type of objects your list contains. First, you should specify the concrete list, here `ArrayList` in your case. You may take a look at the [List Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) to get familiar with.

You should also know that in Java generic type arguments must be objects and because primitives do not extend `Object` they can not be used. So use e.g. `List<Integer>` instead of `List<int>`, since the first one is the wrapper class of `int`. Just take a look at [Wrapper Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Hope this helps you to get more familiar with the topic.